# mixed integer quadratic programming python in pyomo

Tags: cplex, pyomo, quadratic-programming

Can i get a complete example program in pyomo for optimizing quadratic objective functions with constraints with cplex solver?
or an example for mixed integer quadratic programming python in pyomo

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, this is more a pure pyomo question than one having anything to do with CPLEX. The closest I can find is [example4.py](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/examples/pyomo/quadratic/example4.py) (in the pyomo github). This pyomo example only has a quadratic objective function, but it looks like it should be straightforward to modify the `constraint_rule` method to include a quadratic constraint.

Comment: OP might means how to convert CPLEX sparse constraints matrix that will be accepted by pyomo, including setting which variable is integer and whic is not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can modify the model applying duality (Dual Theorem) so you will be able to get a linear objective function with a quadratic constraint. But if you are looking for a double quadratic model, i.e. a quadratic objective function with a quadratic constraint function, you should ensure that one of them is strictly concave and the other strictly convex in order to get only one solution.

Hope help

PS: sorry if I'm late.